# Large function with dynamic array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I created this worksheet function and it works perfectly.

```
=LARGE({1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;0;16;0;0;0;20;21;0;0},1)
```

The problem is how I created it. I started out with the function below which, unfortunately, does **not** work. It returns 0 instead of 21. That is unfortunate because it's precisely this function that I need.

```
=LARGE(ISBLANK(R$1:R23)*ROW(R$1:R23),1)
```

I converted the function I want to the function that works by selecting `ISBLANK(R$1:R23)*ROW(R$1:R23)` in the formula bar and pressing F9. Of course, this action merely displays the array specified by the formula. Therefore the working function and the not working function are technically identical. If you can't tell me how that can be then please try telling me why it is so.

Of course, I tried all the remedies that appeared "obvious". I tried entering the formula as an array formula (no need in Excel 365). I added `--` before the ISBLANK function and tried that with the function in parentheses. All to no avail.

BTW, my purpose is to use the number of the blank sheet row above the cell with the formula in an OFFSET function to return a value from another column in that row. Imagine a block of cells with a title and wanting to reference the title row from any cell in the block, where the title row is identifiable because it has blank cells in the columns where the block has data.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. It would simply return the largest number to me (Using Microsoft365). Btw, you may as well just get the value in the other column through: `=LOOKUP(2,1/(ISBLANK(R$1:R23)),Z$1:Z23)` where I just used `Z:Z` for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Actually, I tried that first. But now I tried it again in a blank workbook after system reboot and got something like "There is a circular reference but I can't show you where", and that set me in what looks like the right direction. The LOOKUP caused the error - pointedly, not the LARGE function - but after excluding row 23 from the lookup array LARGE worked as well. The array can't include the cell with the formula. Thank you for your time and effort!